# Difference Between Rho and Decay Arguments in Keras RMSprop

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, keras, rms

I am working to tune a RNN for the purposes of predictive analytics on time series data. I am testing [different optimizers](https://keras.io/optimizers/#rmsprop) and am currently working with RMSprop.

I have reviewed Hinton's [lecture notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf) on the subject, as well as the Keras documentation on included optimizers. However, for the life of me, I cannot find a good explanation of the difference between `rho` and `decay`.

From [these docs](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/updates.html#lasagne.updates.rmsprop), I know that rho also refers to decay rate, but the difference between the two arguments are anything but clear to me at this point.

```
keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short explanation**

rho is the ["Gradient moving average [also exponentially weighted average] decay factor"](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/updates.html#lasagne.updates.rmsprop) and decay is the ["Learning rate decay over each update"](https://keras.io/optimizers/#rmsprop).

**Long explanation**

RMSProp is defined as follows

[image]
[source](http://index-of.es/Varios-2/Hands%20on%20Machine%20Learning%20with%20Scikit%20Learn%20and%20Tensorflow.pdf)

So RMSProp uses "rho" to calculate an [exponentially weighted average](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/exponentially-weighted-averages-duStO) over the square of the gradients.

Note that "rho" is a direct parameter of the RMSProp optimizer (it is used in the RMSProp formula).

Decay on the other hand handles [learning rate decay](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/learning-rate-decay-hjgIA). Learning rate decay is a mechanism generally applied independently of the chosen optimizer. Keras simply builds this mechanism into the RMSProp optimizer for convenience (as does it with other optimizers like [SGD](https://keras.io/optimizers/#sgd) and [Adam](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) which all have the same "decay" parameter). You may think of the "decay" parameter as "lr_decay".

It can be confusing at first that there are two decay parameters, but they are decaying different values.

- "rho" is the decay factor or the exponentially weighted average over the square of the gradients.
- "decay" decays the learning rate over time, so we can move even closer to the local minimum in the end of training.