# RMSprop difference rho and decay in Tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

As this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351409/difference-between-rho-and-decay-arguments-in-keras-rmsprop) showed nicely, there is a difference between rho and the decay in RMSprop. I can't clearly see what tensorflows RMSprop [parameter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/RMSPropOptimizer) decays stands for. Is this the learning rate decay? And if so, where is the rho?

Comment: With open-source software like TensorFlow the fastest way of finding answers to such questions is by visiting their GitHub page and checking the source code.

Comment: cool haven't thought about that yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the post that you added they talk about RMSprop implementation from keras (it's included in tensorflow), but the other link that you added is original implementation for the RMSProp from tensorflow. Tensorflow's implementation has parameter called `decay`, but it's the same as `rho` in the keras library. But in the RMSProp implantation from keras the `decay` parameter reduced learning rate overtime.

Comment: I thought they were generally speaking about RMSprop having two different kind of decays. (decay factor or the exponentially weighted average over the square of the gradients / decays of the learning rate over time). The tensorflow implementation has however one decay parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, and in tensorflow's implementation the `decay` parameter effects only decay of the squared gradient. They do specify it in the documentation as `Discounting factor for the history/coming gradient`